# Use alias for JOIN using JOOQ's SelectQuery

Tags: sql, join, alias, jooq

I need to write query with nested select and join using JOOQ's SelectQuery:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM (select * from 
    "public"."parent" 
    order by "public"."parent"."setup_time" 
    desc limit 10 offset 0) as "parent1" 
    join "public"."child" 
    on "public"."child"."parent_id" = "parent1"."id" 
    where "public"."child"."name" = 'test'
```

So, I've written something like this:

```
SelectQuery<ParentRecord> subSelectQuery = context.selectQuery(PARENT);
selectQuery.addJoinOnKey(CHILD, JoinType.JOIN, CHILD.PARENT_ID);
```

But it generates sql code like

```
join "public"."child" on "public"."child"."parent_id" =  "public"."parent"."id
```

How can I use alias **parent1** instead of full table name **"public"."child"."parent_id"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution.

```
SelectQuery<ParentRecord> selectQuery = context.selectQuery(subSelectQuery.asTable(PARENT.getName()));
selectQuery.addJoin(CHILD, JoinType.JOIN, CHILD.PARENT_ID.eq(PARENT.as(PARENT.getName()).ID));
```